# A timer to the infinity

Tags: python, timer

I'm working on a script, which will print a *timer* and was trying to reuse a function like this:

```
def timer(m,x):
    for i in range(1,x):
        sys.stdout.write('\r%s\b%d' % (m,i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write('\r  \b')
```

Now, the part of the script, where I want a timer to be displayed is like this:

```
host_alive = "ping -c1 myServer"
cmdStat, cmdOut = commands.getstatusoutput(host_alive)

while True:
    if cmdStat != 0:
        (cmdStat,cmdOut) = commands.getstatusoutput(host_alive)
        print "Still NOT ready!!"
    else:
        break
```

How can I print a timer without specifying a `range()`? Is there any workaround?
Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def timer(m):
    i = 0
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write('\r%s\b%d' % (m,i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write('\r  \b')
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: it's works just fine as a function, but doesn't really fit in my [sample] script. After the second `commands.getstatusoutput()` in the snippet, when I do like this: `timer('Still NOT ready..... ')` it never comes out of the loop and keep continue. Cheers!!

Comment: Any idea how can I breakout of the `timer()`, when `cmdStat` becomes zero (0)? Cheers!!

Comment: instead of "while True:" just write "while cmdStat != 0:"

Answer (score 2):

First of all `commands` module is deprecated and replaced by `subprocess` module.

Secondly, to represent infinity in python you can use `float('inf')`. Its symbolic that you are referring to infinity.

```
def timer(m): 
    i = 0
    while i<float('inf'): #this is symbolic and in essence similar to while True
        sys.stdout.write('\r%s\b%d' % (m,i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write('\r  \b')
        i += 1
```

Comment: I know about the commands but it's an old script. Secondly, you did mean to say: i += 1 - right?

Answer (score 1):

A while loop would probably be a better option here.  Ex:

```
def timer(max):
    while counter > 0:
        print '%d seconds remain' % max
        sleep(1)
        max -= 1
```

Comment: it's not really to the _infinity_ - is it? I wanted the timer to keep going until a certain condition is met. In your example, the upper limit needs to specified, which is completely opposite to me requirement. Cheers!!

Comment: Counting _down_ to infinity makes no sense what so ever.  Unless you mean your timer to go in to negative values.

Comment: Well, that's true! I didn't really mean literately infinity and especially `countdown` but just a __timer__ to run _until_ a certain condition is met. I think I should set a limit for max-run time for the loop. The original post and the subject is corrected now. Cheers!!